# How to echo thumbnails generated on the fly in php?

Tags: php, echo, thumbnails

I am creating thumbnails from images whose path has been stored in a MySQL database. But when I echo the thumbnails, only an image icon is displayed and not the thumbnail picture. What do I need to change? Please keep your answers simple since I am new to PHP.

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
   //database connectivity code
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
   {
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($row['image_path']);

    $width = imagesx($im);
    $height = imagesy($im);

    $imgw = 150;
    $imgh = $height / $width * $imgw;

    $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($imgw,$imgh);

    imagecopyresampled($thumb,$im, 0,0,0,0,$imgw, $imgh, ImageSX($im), ImageSY($im));

    ?>

    <img src = "<?php echo $thumb ?>" >

    <?php
     } //closing while
     ?>
```

I tried to use numerous other functions but none did much help. Most of them displayed an unusually long string of unreadable data. Please point out what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about PHP image functions, but...

The variable $thumb appears to be a resource ID returned from imagecopyresampled. The src attribute on img tags is supposed to be a path to the image file.

Answer (score 0):

This example will not work. You have to create 2 files:

```
<?php

  # image.php file

  $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE id=" . mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['image_id']));
  row = mysql_fetch_array($query)

  $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($row['image_path']);

  $width = imagesx($im);
  $height = imagesy($im);

  $imgw = 150;
  $imgh = $height / $width * $imgw;

  $thumb = imagecreatetruecolor($imgw,$imgh);

  imagecopyresampled($thumb,$im, 0,0,0,0,$imgw, $imgh, ImageSX($im), ImageSY($im));

  imagejpeg($thumb, null, 100);
?>
```

and then in your html you can put

```
<?php

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{  
   echo '<img src = "image.php?image_id='.$row['id'].'">';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. I tried it out, but it doesn't seem to work this way either. It still displays only image icons in place of the thumbnails.

Comment: Can you much more from your code? this approach should work but it depends on your environment

Comment: Well I figured it out. I had to replace the echo statement you suggested to this: <img src = "<?php echo 'image.php?image_id='.$row['image_id'].?> with the php tags inside <img>, though I don't know why. Thanks a lot for the help :)